# Will (or "do") people in heaven get to interact with Jesus, independent of massive crowds?

Tags: life-of-jesus, heaven, eschatology

When one considers the example Jesus set during his time on earth, and compares it with how individuals often treat each other, the sharp contrast between "how the world works" and "how things should be" becomes visible -- and, at times, rather tiresome.

While we don't know how many people will get to heaven, it seems that it will certainly be "a lot" -- far more than could reasonably expect to have extensive conversations with Christ on a regular basis, for example. And I imagine that the Son of God probably will be (or "is") quite busy with very important matters.

**So, will (or "do") individuals, or groups of, say, ten or a dozen people in heaven have an opportunity to interact with Jesus, independent of massive crowds?** Is there some equivalent of going fishing with Christ? Or will he be like a celebrity who, under normal circumstances, often finds it necessary to maintain a certain distance, because of the crowds? Will there be something like "town hall meetings," where he stops by different parts of heaven every so often and talks with the local residents? Will those who lived more righteous lives and so "stored up more treasure in heaven" have preferential access to God's time? Or is there some other alternative?

Edit:
***Clarification:*** This question assumes: 1) Christ, in heaven, will / does exist in a resurrected body; 2) Many people will vie for his time, resulting in frequent crowding.

- If the assumptions are wrong, what makes them so?
- **If the assumptions are correct, would Christ somehow still be able to regularly interact with his followers, independent of the crowds?**

/Edit

I hope that some responses will include citations of historic authors, exegesis supported by substantial commentators.

Comment: @DavidStratton The question in the title is misleading, and the content has a lot of fluff. But I think the real question here is: "Will individuals in heaven have an opportunity to interact with Jesus?" -- which, IMO, is appropriate for this site.

Comment: @DavidS: The Bible contains a wealth of material that describes heaven. If you think that there is "no Scriptural reference on this," then the reasonable, adult response would be to create a response to that effect. I think it's a legitimate question  that's appropriate for the site.

Comment: Ok. Retracted. As slight as the edits were, they were enough to drastically improve the question.

Comment: @DavidS: The only edit that was not prior to your comment was made by someone who changed the title to something that was already part of the question.

Comment: and that was enough. slight, but enough.

Comment: @DavidS: The sharp contrast of the disposition evinced by your comments, on the one hand, and what can be expected from Christ, on the other, provides a remarkable example of the behavior referenced in the first sentence of the question, making things even more clear. Thanks for that. [*2 Timothy 2*](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2tim%202:22-26&version=ESV).

Comment: God is not limited by time (cf. 2 Pet 3:8). I don't think that God would let neither time nor space hinder him from spending "time" alone with his beloved in heaven. :)

Comment: @Matt: I wrote the title as an attention grabber and intended it to elicit response -- and apparently, from the number of comments, I succeeded. As for what you're calling "fluff," from an analytical perspective, it's important for a question that defies a simple, rote answer to provide context, in order to encourage responses that are focused.

Comment: I would suggest splitting your edit off into a new question. Your original and your new one are definitely separate enough that there would be no problem with putting the new one in its own question.

Comment: The question seems to assume Heaven will have the same physical structure as our currently known Universe. Maybe Heaven has more than 3 dimensions of space and more than one dimension of time, however incomprehensible this is for us now?

Answer (score 5):

According to the christian soterology, not only in heaven you can interact with Christ, but also here, on earth. We know from the lifes of saint Silvan of Athos or saint Seraphim of Sarov that they have seen Christ himself.

Of course there are people who believe that this form of interaction isn't a real interaction with God. It is only some created thing that we can see from the God's will. This view was however condemned by saint Gregory Palamas. So this is at least what Orthodox Christians firmly believe. If you are not Orthodox, you may not accept it.

On the other hand - if we are unable to interact with Christ in heaven, then what kind of heaven it would be? Why would it be desireable for us? Imagining heaven as full of bodily pleasures is rather muslim thing not christian. For a christian the main goal is always Christ and his love.

Two quotations from Bible to support the idea:

And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, To day shalt thou be **with me** in paradise (Luke 23, 43)

For I am in a strait betwixt two, having a desire to depart, **and to be with Christ**; which is far better (Philippians 1, 23)

Answer (score 3):

The basis and inspiration for this answer is a great book named Beautiful Outlaw by John Eldredge. This book delves into the personality of Jesus by taking well-known stories in the Gospels and bringing them to life. We tend to think of Jesus as being too Holy for us, when in fact people *flocked* to Him and He was the most human man ever (He was fully God and fully man, and [emptied Himself](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202:6-7&version=ESV) of His divinity).

Jesus was just as human as the rest of us. He [dealt with our temptations](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews+4:15&version=NLT), He [cried](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2011:35&version=NLT), He got [lonely](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206:66-67&version=NLT), He [felt the need to be by Himself](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206:46&version=NLT) after [the death of His cousin](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206:27-29&version=NLT), He got [angry](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=jesus+clears+the+temple&qs_version=NLT), He was [joyful](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2015:11&version=NLT), He was [playful](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2024:13-35&version=NLT), He was [capable of surprise](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+7:9&version=NLT), and He [took shortcuts](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%206:16-21&version=NLT).

Crowds flocked to Jesus wherever He went, to the point that even [going across a lake didn't keep them back](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206:22-25&version=NLT). People with disabilities were constantly seeking Him out and going to Him for healing, like the [two blind men that called out](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2020:29-34&version=NLT), the [woman who had been bleeding internally for twelve years](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%208:43-44&version=NLT), and [the blind and lame](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2021:14&version=NLT) *immediately* after Jesus clears the temple. The guy that [denied Jesus three times](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2022:54-62&version=NLT) (and then had Jesus look *straight* at him) was the same guy that [put on his clothes, jumped into the water, and swam at least a mile to shore to Jesus](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2021:7&version=NLT). Jesus was also willing to [get up in the middle of the night](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:1-2&version=NLT) to talk to a true seeker.

Jesus was extravagantly generous (what else do you call [605-908 bottles of the *best* wine](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%202:6-10&version=NLT)?) and [loved everyone equally](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%203:16&version=NLT) ([even the children!](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2019:13-15&version=NLT)). Jesus was also [quite personal and intimate](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+9:2&version=NLT) and will personal and intimate be in Heaven as well ([the white stone engraved with a name that only two people know](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%202:17&version=NLT)).

---

> While we don't know how many people will get to heaven, it seems that it will certainly be "a lot" -- far more than could reasonably expect to talk to Christ on a regular basis, for example. And I imagine that the Son of God probably will be (or "is") quite busy with very important matters.
>
> **So, will (or "do") individuals in heaven have an opportunity to interact with Jesus?** Is there some equivalent of going fishing with Christ? Or will he be like a celebrity who, under normal circumstances, maintains a certain distance? Will there be something like "town hall meetings," where he stops by different parts of heaven every so often and talks with the local residents? Will those who lived more righteous lives and so "stored up more treasure in heaven" have preferential access to God's time? Or is there some other alternative?

First off, [Jesus is God](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2010:30&version=NLT). If He wants to talk with multiple people in person simultaneously, nothing's stopping Him. Also, given what I've pointed out, there's NO WAY that Jesus would let "very important matters" keep Him from interacting with the people He loved (and loves) SO MUCH that He died for them. I don't see why Jesus wouldn't go fishing with someone who loved fishing, and He definitely wouldn't be distant like a celebrity. Nor would He spend more time with people who had been believers longer (cue [this parable about vineyard workers](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2020:1-16&version=NLT)). Ha, if anything, He'd spend more time with those who *weren't* believers all their lives! ([Finding that one lost sheep was cause enough for great joy.](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2018:12-13&version=NLT))

Finally, [Jesus Himself is preparing a room for us](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+14:2&version=NLT) and we'll get to [live there for eternity](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians+5:10&version=NLT)!

Comment: +1. Great answer, thank you. Do you know if the Bible says whether Christ will exist in a resurrected body, the way I think it says believers will? If so, would that prevent him from being in more than one place at a time? Maybe I should add that to the question.

Comment: @JBunyan: [John 20:19,26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020:19,26&version=NLT) Jesus didn't let piddly things like locked doors keep Him from appearing to the disciples in His resurrected body...

Comment: Interesting. Is there any record of him appearing in more than one location at the same time?

Comment: @JBunyan: Not to my knowledge. Then again, He's God. What part of being God prevents Him from being in two places at once? :P

Comment: I'm not sure; that's why I'm looking in the Bible and asking among a group of people that describe themselves as "experts," in order to avoid the emotion-laden, self-important vitriol that is often provided by people that call themselves "Christians."

Answer (score 0):

A few verses:

Jesus personally eats with His disciples:

> Matthew 26:29 But I say unto you, I will not drink henceforth of this fruit of the vine, until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.

Notice the way Jesus interacts with the people:

> Revelation 3:12 Him that overcometh will I make a pillar in the temple of my God, and he shall go no more out: and I will write upon him the name of my God, and the name of the city of my God, which is new Jerusalem, which cometh down out of heaven from my God: and I will write upon him my new name.

"I will make...", "I will write..." - Jesus personally does these things

> Revelation 3:21 To him that overcometh will I grant to sit with me in my throne, even as I also overcame, and am set down with my Father in his throne.

You can see the personal care given by Jesus to the redeemed:

> Revelation 7:17 For the Lamb which is in the midst of the throne shall feed them, and shall lead them unto living fountains of waters: and God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes.

The imagery of the good Shepherd is used here. The lamb shall feed them.

Then there is a special group:
Speaking about the hundred and forty four thousand, the Bible says:

> Revelation 14:4 These are they which were not defiled with women; for they are virgins. These are they which follow the Lamb whithersoever he goeth. These were redeemed from among men, being the firstfruits unto God and to the Lamb.

In Jesus's own words:

> Luke 12:37 Blessed are those servants, whom the lord when he cometh shall find watching: verily I say unto you, that he shall gird himself, and make them to sit down to meat, and will come forth and serve them.